# Designing a Peristaltic Pump Driver with IRFZ44n Mosfet

Tags: arduino, mosfet, fluid-pump

I'm making a peristaltic pump controlled by an arduino. The pump is controlled by a PWM from arduino to a IRFZ44N Mosfet. I have added a pulldown resistor for the gate, and also diode and capacitor for the pump in paralell Here is my schematics, I think it will explains better:
[image]

But the problem is, after I have turned on the pump on high PWM (i.e: analogWrite(outputPin, 200)) after sometime the pump would turn on continuously for a while and the arduino would resets. Any idea why does this happens?

The peristaltic pump is 12V 5W, and here the VCC in the schematics is 12V

Comment: Is that your whole circuit? There doesn't appear to be any decoupling. I've not used an arduino, but most microcontrollers have a register containing the reset reason, it would be worth seeing if there is one, it will tell you if it's a brown out or similar.

Comment: okay, I will try adding a decoupling capacitor on the Vin, and will update here

Comment: Thank you @Colin that pretty much solves my problem! I will keep in mind to put decoupling capacitor on my voltage source next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, as Colin suggested. I should have added a decoupling capacitor on my voltage source to prevent brown out. So, here is my updated schematics in case someone needs it in the future:

[image]